# What is the definitive EBNF syntax?

Tags: parsing, grammar, ebnf

I am currently using the [lark parser for python](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to try and read in some problem specifications.  I am getting confused about what the "proper" syntax is for Extended Backus-Naur form, especially about how the LHS and RHS are separated.  The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form#Conventions) uses an equals `=` sign, lark expects just a colon; see [lark cheat sheet](https://www.cheatography.com/erezsh/cheat-sheets/lark/).  Other sources use the `::=` separator - e.g. the [atom ebnf package](https://atom.io/packages/ebnf).

Is there a definitive answer?  The [official ISO spec](https://www.iso.org/standard/26153.html) seems to suggest that the "defining-symbol" should be `=` but there seems to be wriggle room in the spec.  So why all the different versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the world hasn't yet appointed a Lord High Commissioner of Grammar Formalisms, there is no definitive syntax. You're certainly free to use the ISO "Extended BNF" standard, particularly if you're writing some other ISO standard, but don't expect it to be implemented by a parser generator, even one which extends normal BNF. (There's no definitive standard for BNF, either.)

I have no way of knowing what was going on in the minds of the authors of the ISO standard, but I suspect that their expectations were realistic: it's intended to allow precise description of syntaxes for standards documents, but there are many features which are not suitable for automated implementation (including a way of writing rule restrictions in English to be used when the formalism isn't sufficiently general). It's often possible to automatically extract (most of) a grammar from an ISO standard, but the task is neither simple nor -- as far as I can see -- intended to be simple, since most ISO standards are not distributed as plain text documents and extracting formatted text from either PDF or HTML formats presents its own challenges.

The options you present for punctuation are most of the common ones, although mathematicians often write BNF using ⇒ to separate left- and right-hand sides. (Unfortunately, most keyboards lack that useful character.)

I'm personally not fond of the `::=` separator, although it is used by various parser generators. It seems to me to be way too much typing for a simple punctuator, and it is also annoyingly difficult to align with alternatives flagged with `|`. But to each their own.